# Making cut-out fliers in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

I'm creating fliers to hand out, but I don't want to use a full sheet of paper for each flier... I'd like to use my existing .pdf, shrink it down, and perhaps get 4-8 copies of it per page so I can cut them out to save paper.

Are there any existing classes or ideas in this regard? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The package [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) can include all pages from an included PDF file and the option `nup=2x2` allows multiple pages per sheet. I recommend seeing [the manual (link)](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages): usage of `\includepdf` and `nup` option is explained at pages 2-3 of that manual.